# Magento New Rupee Symbol. why is it visible on chrome not on firefox?

Tags: php

Does anyone knows any way to display the New Indian Rupee sumbol. Following the normal method, sIt is visible on chrome not on all pages, but certainly not in firefox. Can anyone suggest a solution or any other way?

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

₹ `&#8377;` is the code for new indian rupee symbol

Comment: Thanks a ton, I tried it was working fine on some pages but not all pages. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Not all fonts on all platforms have support for that code point, at this time.  You might switch to a font that does, for that one character; or you might make a small image of the character and display that.  Here's a short summary of how the rupee symbol is supported: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee_sign#Unicode

**Update**

You can also use the Local Fontlist Tool [at FileFormat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/fontsupport.htm) to determine which of the fonts installed on your own machine support the character.  That's no guarantee, however, that visitors to your web site will have the same fonts, upgraded for rupee symbol support.  For instance, the Arial on my Windows 7 machine supports it, but the Arial on my old Mac OS 10.5 does not.